# How to avoid recompile on file changes?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

How can I avoid a recompile in Angular 8 when using `ng serve` if files in directory `./rest` have been changed? I checked out many solutions and at first I thought that `exclude` flag in tsconfig is the solution, but it doesn't work.

```
ROOT
 |_ app
 |__ ...
 |_ rest
```

Comment: `ng serve --prod`

Comment: @Reactgular it only simulates the app in production, but does not stop recompilation on file change

Comment: I started playing around with this and exclude and could not get files ignored.  Bug with some more info: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/2425 Looks like the full src directory is watched and there is currently no exclude functionality. When you exclude something, you have to also exclude all files that include it and at some point you won't have an app that builds https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6050 . Also worth noting it looks like you can use a GLOB to prevent assets from being watched: https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#assets-configuration

Comment: Are you saying that `ng serve` watches by default? When did they change that? I've always added `--watch` and I'm not sure I like the idea of it being turned on by default.

Comment: Wait a minute. `ng serve --prod` should not hot reload changes. If that is true, then this implies that a production build also includes the hot module reloading scripts. Which is a dirty build to me. `--prod` should match production without any dev dependencies.

Comment: in ng serve --prod you will get the built for production one, but if it detects changes it relbuilds it

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a solution that only some files or directories were excluded from "auto-compilation", but not to disable the whole auto-compilation system. I could find a solution to exclude some directories by using the configurations:

```
    "build": {
      "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
      "options": {
        ...
        "assets": [
         { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
       ],
       ...
      },

      "configurations": {
        "production": {
           "assets": [
            { "glob": "**/*", "input": "src/assets/", "output": "/assets/" },
            { "glob": "**/*", "input": "rest/", "output": "/rest/" },
          ],
          ...
```

Now all files in `rest/` are ignored when some files will be changed.